Profit at lower timeframe
Assume I have a chart timeframe of 1 min, and I have a strategy that buys and sells on 1 min chart. Strategy tester provides per-trade profit as well as cumulative profit.
How can I see how the profit is playing out in lower timeframe, such as 5sec or 1sec?
I cannot use calc_on_every_tick as it works only on a real-time basis and forward testing.
I also tried request.security but I do not know what to put as argument in request.security to get second by second profit.
Thanks.
I tried request.security, but it returns zero.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The strategy tester will only show the results that whatever timeframe you are on.
If you want to get the results from the lower timeframes, then you need to change your chart's timeframe.
If you really want to see the results on the seconds timeframe, then you need to have at least a Premium account. With that, you can also use the deep backtesting feature so you can get more data (time-wise) for your strategy.
